# Associations not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise, associations

When a user cancels their account on my application their **user record** is correctly removed from the database but their **profile record** still seems to exist. Below are my models for user and profile, any solutions?

**Profile.rb**

```
 class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
 end
```

**user.rb**

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :profile

   #callback that creates a profile for each user that signs up
   after_create :create_profile
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
   :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  private
    def create_profile
     self.profile = Profile.create
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify explicitly what to do with dependent model.

As example

```
has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
```

There are some other options like `:delete`, `:nullify`. You can take a look at them here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one

Answer (score 1):

It will also delete the association too.

```
has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
```

source: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html